# Why are special characters being added at the end of my text converted from PHP?

Tags: php, html, ms-word

So I get these values from a form and they are then saved into a word document.

If my input (this is a textarea by the way) reads this:

```
"This"
&
"That"
```

I would expect the output to be exactly like that

However, whenever it comes out it looks like this:

[image]

It adds those special block characters at the end...

How can I get rid of these?

These are my variables:

```
$multipleImports = explode("\n",$_POST['multipleImports']);
$multipleImportsInfo = explode("\n",$_POST['multipleImportsInfo']);
$multipleImportsCounts = explode("\n",$_POST['multipleImportsCounts']);
```

And here I concatenate them into a string.

```
$length = count($multipleImports);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $content = $content . $multipleImports[$i] . "          " . $multipleImportsInfo[$i] . "          " . $multipleImportsCounts[$i] . "\n ";
}
```

I tried to right trim, I tried to use html entities and html decode entities and nothing I tried worked. Please help.

Comment: Well, first thing to do obviously is to look what characters those are, actually. Use a `hexeditor` for that.

Comment: @arkascha Okay, let me download one real quick and see.

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to know what those special characters are. You should do a hex dump to see. I just glanced at your code and haven't thought seriously about it, but what immediately pops into my mind is the different in end-of-line in Windows vs. *nix. That is, if the data comes from Windows I think the end of line is provided by a carriage return AND line feed ("\r\n") rather than by just a line feed ("\n").

Comment: This is _not_ an answer, it should have been a comment.

Comment: I have to agree with @arkascha's comment, but this did make me think about it and identify the problem! At the end of my string I changed it to "\r\n" which actually worked beautfiully.

Comment: @rohanharrison I don't see how that should provoke or solve the issue you described. Especially since the line break in web pages is something completely different all together. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Well I was essentially doing a \r\n but more manually. Once I just changed it from \n (space) to \r\n it did exactly what I needed to do and honestly that's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Tom Hedden's post it gave me an idea to try this, and it worked!

```
$length = count($multipleImports);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $content = $content . $multipleImports[$i] . "          " . $multipleImportsInfo[$i] . "          " . $multipleImportsCounts[$i] . "\r\n ";
}
```